# Jenkins Xcode build alamofire error

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, alamofire

I am trying to setup Jenkins for Continuous Integration with Xcode. I am using the Xcode integration plugin, however, when I run the build for Debug, it keeps saying that the Alamofire file is missing:

```
no such module 'Alamofire'
import Alamofire
   ^
```

Alamofire has been added as a submodule through GIT.

When I run the project in Xcode though, it works perfectly. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue.

It has been solved by below steps.

1. click manage scheme
2. enable the shared checkbox in that window. [Please see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVp7u.png)